# Setting Jquery UI slider's initial value from an input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to generalize some slider code so that it will work with a few input + slider combinations.

I have everything essentially working - slide the slider, the input value updates or enter a number in the input, the slider moves to the proper location.

However, I'm having trouble initializing the sliders from the default values of the inputs. Here's what my code looks like:

**Javascript**

```
$(".slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        value: $(this).parent().find(".inputNumber").val(),
        step: 0.25,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().find(".inputNumber").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="inputWrap hidden">
    <input class="mini inputNumber" type="text" value="0.5">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works for me (with any number of sliders):

```
$(".slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 0.25,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().find(".inputNumber").val(ui.value);
    },
    create: function(event, ui){
        $(this).slider('value',$(this).parent().find(".inputNumber").val());
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/uv5aC/

Comment: Thanks - didn't know about the create option. Big help.

Comment: Works for any number of sliders unless those sliders are from Good Times... Then red death.

Answer (score 3):

this seems to work

```
$(".slider").each(function(){
    $(this).slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 0.25,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().find(".inputNumber").val(ui.value);
    }
}).slider( "option", "value", $(this).parent().find(".inputNumber").val() );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uMgnX/2/)

Comment: but what if he has multiple sliders and multiple inputNumber?

Comment: I do in fact need this to work for more than one slider, which this answer unfortunately, does not: http://jsfiddle.net/hte2B/1/